# Getting static constant from a class using mirrors in dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I'm trying to get the `BYTES_PER_ELEMENT` constant in Float32List (and other typed data arrays) using mirrors, but all I'm getting is the exception `No static getter 'BYTES_PER_ELEMENT' declared in class 'Float32List'.` So more generally,  how can I access the static constants of a class?

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:mirrors';

main() {
  var array = new Float32List(10);

  var bytesPerElement = reflect(array).type.getField(#BYTES_PER_ELEMENT).reflectee;

  print(bytesPerElement);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Float32List()` is a factory constructor which returns a `_Float32Array` which doesn't have `BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`.

```
print(reflect(array).type);
```

prints

```
ClassMirror on '_Float32Array'
```

```
var bytesPerElement = 
    reflectClass(Float32List)
    .getField(#BYTES_PER_ELEMENT)
    .reflectee;
```

prints

```
4
```

I'm pretty sure it is not possible to find a way back from `_Float32Array` to  `Float32List` using mirrors.